# SSIS Convert 2:00 PM to 14:00:00 in CSV to SQL Server Import

Tags: csv, ssis, sql-server-2016

**Problem**

A value of `2:00 PM` in .csv file gets imported into SQL Server as `02:00:00` instead of `14:00:00`

**Context**

- I have a source .csv file that has a time only value of 2:00 PM.
- If I open the file in Excel, I can change the column format to `h:mm:ss` and it will display 14:00:00, but I don't want to have to open and change that.
- The sql server column it is imported into is of type `time(7)'

**Question**

How can I make it so the time will be converted from 12 hr to 24 hour?

Comment: How is the column defined in the connection manager for the flat file?

Comment: @EricBrandt database time with precision [DT_DBTIME2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please add a Data Conversion between Your Source and destination as below.

Let's say our source file is like this:

[image: FRST]

DFT Full Package View:

[image: MainFlow]

If we go inside Data Conversion,

[image: DFT_DC]

And if we run the package and check it in Management studio after creating a table there (One column TIME(7) format)

[image: Final Result Set]

I hope It works for you!